Черный экран после подключения из windows к ubuntu 22.04 по протоколу xrdp
Черный экран после подключения из windows к ubuntu 22.04 по протоколу xrdp в локальной сети.
устанавливал так:
sudo apt update
sudo ufw allow 3389
sudo apt install xrdp
sudo apt install xorgxrdp
sudo systemctl enable xrdp
sudo systemctl status xrdp
sudo apt install xfce4
sudo systemctl start xrdp

Удаленно подключается, а изображения нет. Подскажите пожалуйста что может быть?



Какая версия xrdp? Какое содержимое файла: /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh

версия xrdp 0.9.17 устанавливал сегодня

файл скрин добавил в вопрос

Попробуйте в этот файл, перед 13 строкой добавить это: unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

И перезапустить xrdp : sudo systemctl restart xrdp

спасибо помогло.

как я могу поставить ваш ответ верным?

Добавил в виде ответа.

Добавьте в файл /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh, перед предпоследней строкой, код:
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

И перезапустите службу xrdp:
sudo systemctl restart xrdp


подскажите пожалуйста это нормально что изображения на экранах разные? я не вижу своих ярлыков на рабочем столе, и открытых окон. Хотя пользователь один всего.

Вы имеете в виду, что отличаются экраны при локальном входе и при подключении по rdp?

да, при работе непосредственно на сервере экран отличается от того если одновременно войти через xrdp c другого компьютера.
